# Accessing hidden method MotionEvent->init on Dark greylist

Tags: android, delphi

I am programming an Android App in Delphi Firemonkey, when i click on the screen and tab out of the app, i get this error in Logcat:

```
Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/MotionEvent;-><init>()V (dark greylist, JNI)
```

And this Popup text:

> Detected Problems with API compatibility (visit g.co/appcompat for more info)

I am using Delphi 10.3

Comment: The problem is fixed in Delphi 10.3.1

Comment: @DaveNottage Okay, i try to update Delphi thanks!

Comment: I have just upgraded to 10.3.2 and I am seeing this problem.

Comment: Seems this same symbol is now rearing its ugly head as a "StrictMode policy violation" when submitting apps to the Google Play store: https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/programming-languages/f/delphi-language/68893/android-compatibility-warning---strictmode-policy-violation