# Fix Landroid/view/MotionEvent incompatibility

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I am programming an Android App in Delphi Sydney FMX, I have an Android incompatibility in GooglePlayConsole when submitting my app:

```
Landroid/view/MotionEvent;-><init>()V

StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Landroid/view/MotionEvent;-><init>()V
```

By reading [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56427997/accessing-hidden-method-motionevent-init-on-dark-greylist) I have a beginning of answer but the most relevant answer accesses a broken link.

Regards

Comment: Check the targetSdkVersion value in AndroidManifest.xml (i.e. not the template) in your application deployment. Make sure it is 28 or greater

Comment: I checked in AndroidManifest.xml: minSdkVersion is 23 and targetSdkVersion is 29

Comment: In Google Play Console API levels is 23+ and SDK target 29

Comment: Can you confirm exactly which version of Delphi? e.g. is it 10.4.1?

Comment: This is Delphi 10.4.1